# The specified child already has a parent.when I do layout.addView(button, params);

Tags: android, view, textview

When you try to add mdescrition in the view

```
mDescriptHelp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id_descript_help); 
mDescriptHelp.setTypeface(mFontUtils.getBentonSansMediumFont());

TelephonyManager manager = 
         (TelephonyManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(800, 290, 10, 0);
    layout.addView(mDescriptHelp, params);
}
```

And my error is

```
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I don't understand the error. Any idea? I hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: You should not do such a thing.
Remove id_descript_help TextView from your layout.xml, and create this view programmatically by: mDescriptHelp = new TextView(mContext); and then try to add it to layout. By placing view in layout.xml you declare its parent and you cannot move it

Comment: Probably you want to show/hide this TextView if condition (getPhoneType() == PHONE_TYPE_NONE" is true, then maybe you should try use mDescriptHelp.setVisibility(View.GONE) to hide view and View.VISIBLE to show it

Comment: I need to do this way because I have to differentiate when it's tablet. if it's smartphone, I don't add params.

Comment: In this case you should specify this layout.xml with different res folders – for phones (default without postfix) and for tablets (with postfix, -sw600dp, for example). For more information I strongly suggest you to read articles on android.developers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change this line

```
layout.addView(mDescriptHelp, params);
```

to

```
mDescriptHelp.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I think that it's the way.

Answer (score 0):

mDescriptHelp= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id_descript_help);

Here is your problem. You already have mDescription inside a View tree or else you wouldn't find it by findViewById()